# Question about $e$ element at $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

At group $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$, $e=0$?

I assume that is true but I just what to know if I'm right.

Because for every $a\in \mathbb{Z}_{n}, a^0=a\cdot 0=0$.

Thank you!

Comment: The neutral element is the class of $0$ modulo $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I'm assuming you mean the additive group: $\mathbb Z_n$, under addition modulo $n$, where for $a \in \mathbb Z_n$, $a^n$ means $\underbrace{a + a +\cdots + a}_{n\;\text{times}} = n\cdot a.\;$

Then, indeed, the identity of $\;\mathbb Z_n\,$ is $\,e = 0$.